# VS2022 Primary Constructor quick action not complete

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, primary-constructor

## Problem

When creating a class with a primary constructor, the quick actions for adding another parameter in the constructor do not work as expected. The actual assignment of the constructor parameter to the field is skipped.

## How to recreate

Starting from this class:

```cs
public class MyExample(SomeDependency dependency1)
{
    readonly SomeDependency _dependency1 = dependency1;
    readonly ILogger<MyExample> _logger;
}
```

The `_logger` isn't initialized yet, but the quick actions suggest "Add parameters to MyExample(SomeDependency dependency1)...". By doing this, the class is altered to this:

```cs
public class MyExample(SomeDependency dependency1, ILogger<MyExample> logger)
{
    readonly SomeDependency _dependency1 = dependency1;
    readonly ILogger<MyExample> _logger;
}
```

The parameter is added but not assigned to the `_logger` field.

## Expected behavior

Besides adding the logger parameter to the primary constructor, it should be assigned to the `_logger` field.

```cs
public class MyExample(SomeDependency dependency1, ILogger<MyExample> logger)
{
    readonly SomeDependency _dependency1 = dependency1;
    readonly ILogger<MyExample> _logger = logger;
}
```

Comment: So the real question is why does the action `Add parameters to.. ` not assign them to some arbitrary field as well? The name is `add`, not `add and assign to field`. `logger` is already available in the entire class as a quasy-hidden field. You don't really need `_dependency1` and `_logger`. The hidden field is skipped if the field and parameter name are the same. You can test this at [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAExAagD4AEBMBGAsAKHQGYACLEgYQApYAXEqAShIG8CSOGZ6oBeKANztOxMgBYSAWSrM2+TgobJe2IfM4BfAhqA)

Comment: All uninitialized fields have this quick action and this follows normal constructors. So this is not a problem but a feature request.

Comment: @NTE you accepted a bad answer. Readonly fields are perfectly fine. What you describe is probably a quirk (bug?) in the Visual Studio action, nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary constructors don't support readonly fields.

So if we take this

```
public class MyExample(SomeDependency dependency1)
{
    readonly SomeDependency _dependency1 = dependency1;
    readonly ILogger<MyExample> _logger;
    
}
```

If you want to initialise `_logger`, as it is a readonly field then you need to do it in a "full fat" constructor.  You can't use a primary constructor (as it stands today)

But you are also effectively just duplicating the number of fields in your class in the way you use it today.  You don't need to redeclare them in your class.

If SomeDependency had a property like this

```
public class SomeDependency
{
    public string MyData {get;set;}

}
```

With your current declaration, you could use this as follows

```
public class MyExample(SomeDependency dependency1)
{
    readonly SomeDependency _dependency1 = dependency1;
    //removed _logger for simplicity

    public void MyUsage()
    {
        var string1 = dependency1.MyData;
        var string2 = _dependency1.MyData;
    }
}
```

So both `dependecy1` and `_dependency1` both exist in your class and are the same reference.  So it makes no sense.

What you can do is "convert" the fields to properties like this;

```
public class MyExample(SomeDependency dependency1)
{
    public SomeDependency MyDependencyProperty { get; } = dependency1;
```

By just using the getter, then it is readonly from outside the class, but of course remaining mutable from inside.

Although I think this will still generate warnings from the compiler.

Comment: Where is it mentioned that readonly fields aren't supported? Was this assertion actually tested? Primary constructors are syntactic sugar that get translated to proper constructors [as this Sharplab example shows](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAExAagD4AEBMBGAsAKHQGYACLEgYQApYAXEqAShIG8CSOSAnAUwgQD2MADYBPBjHoB9KAF4oAbgIBfIA===)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Nick Chapsis explains this in his video much better than I can. 
 https://youtu.be/IABO8O9cZOw?si=P_HRLlNlGwUwM94s&t=245

Comment: Videos aren't language references or compilers. Readonly fields work perfectly fine. I suspect you misunderstood what that video says. Or the video is isn't as well edited as it should. The editing and quality criteria for YouTube videos are a lot lower than courses, which are lower than magazine articles and books. I use `readonly ILogger` and primary constructors in a lot of places

Comment: Besides, the question was about the VS action, not about compilation problems. If you try to set a readonly field you'll see it works perfectly fine